# generic method write to a list

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic method which accepts a list of numbers in the format below. I know that I should be able to add any class to the list "o" which is at least a number (floats, integers, doubles) BUT also I should be able to add any object because all classes extend from object. In other words, object is a super class of any classs. So I wonder, why do I get an error on the line o.add(p); ?

```
public int checkType(List<? super Number> o) 
{
   Object p = new Object();
   //error
   o.add(p);
   return - 1;
 }
```

I followed the explanation of generics from [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) which is the accepted answer.

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @kocko the question is not a duplicate

Comment: @Ferdinand Nema see above

Comment: I thought it should be `List<? extends Number> o` as the parameter. So its applied to any object that extends Number, such as those native wrapper objects.

Comment: @kocko see my explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type-parameter `List<? super Number> o` specifies that any `List` which can hold a `Number` can be passed to it.

Which could be `List<Object>`, but that could also be `List<Number>`.

So compiler will allow you to add only `Number` (or subtype) objects to it.

To test, call your methods with the following arguments.

```
checkType(new ArrayList<Object>()); // Works fine (and it can hold Object type).
checkType(new ArrayList<Number>()); // Works fine (But it can NOT hold Object type).
```

So, as you see a `List<? super Number>` means that you are trying to add a `Number` to the list (Rule of PECS).

Comment: checkType(new ArrayList<Object>()); works fine but then o.add(p); still doesn't work!

Comment: @george, that's the whole point of PECS... The parameter is not restricted to just `List<Object>`... But `List<Number>` also... And you cannot put an object inside a `List<Number>`.. So the compiler error...

Answer (score 0):

One consideration?

```
List<Object> myObjectList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, new SuperObject(), 4, 5);
```

Java comes standard with a utility class `Arrays`.